# How to open file inside folder in current directory using fopen?

Tags: c, fopen

I want to open a file that is inside a folder in the current working directory like so:

```
fopen("/folder/file.txt","r");
```

I'm unable to do so in this way, I get a `No such file or directory` error.

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 12):

You have to mention that is a current directory. Try this,

```
fopen("./folder/file.txt","r");
```

Or

```
fopen("folder/file.txt","r");
```

If you mentioning like this `/folder/file.txt` it will search the directory from the root directory. So this is the reason for getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
fopen("./folder/file.txt","r"); /* dot means the directory itself */
```

or

```
fopen("folder/file.txt","r"); /* without the first backslash */
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that if I remove the first backslash it works.

Like so:

```
fopen("folder/file.txt","r");
```

Weird.

Comment: It's not "weird". It's just normal.

Comment: it's not weird, when you say `"/folder/file.txt"`, the function looks at `folder` at root directory (in UNIX)

Comment: It's not weird at all. If you start a file path with a slash, it means that you are looking from the root directory, and not from the current directory.

Answer (score -1):

```
int folder;
char* foldername="Ricci";
folder = mkdir(foldername);
DIR* opendir(foldername);
printf("folder successfully created\n");
FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("Ricci/database.txt","a");
```